# Disable double at(@) sign in exim

Tags: email, exim

How do I disable double at sign in message-ID?

because of the double at, my e-mails are entering recipients spam folder:

> 001d01d2d093$7154f9d0$53feed70$ **@** USER **@** domain.tld

in the log, I see the above message header, and the mail-tester.com, notes this issue

> "Message-ID contains multiple '@' characters"

Any idea how I can disable the doube at sign in exim??

---

Detailed log output:

> USER@domeinname.tld  F= R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=16179 H=OFFICE365domain-COM.mail.protection.outlook.com [213.199.180.170] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 C="250 2.6.0 <001d01d2d093$7154f9d0$53feed70$ **@** USER **@** domain.tld> [InternalId=2070174243006, Hostname=VI1PR0601MB2605.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com] 23799 bytes in 0.280, 82.980 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-message_processing.html says that the message-id includes "@ and the primary host name. "

Your log message above seems to indicate that `USER@domeinname.tld` is the name of your host.

If that's true, then you need to give your host a name that does not include an @.

You might also check your exim configuration:

> Additional information can be included in this header line by setting the **message_id_header_text** and/or **message_id_header_domain** options.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but, the issue [I think] is `001d01d2d093$7154f9d0$53feed70$ @ USER @ domain.tld`. And in the previous log, I malfored the log, i hade some things wrong, It is now edited. I check everything else, and there is an Excual rule in SpamAssising that block double at signs: https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/MSGID_MULTIPLE_AT